# How to vertically center when opening a file:line from emacsclient?

Tags: emacsclient, scrolling

Is there a way to center the vertical scroll position when using emacs client to open a file at a position?

eg:

```
emacsclient +$NUM:$COL $FILE --no-wait --alternate-editor=emacs
```

---

Is it possible to either:

- Modify this command so it tells emacs to recenter.
- Add to a hook that runs `(recenter)` after has opened a file from a remote request?

Comment: `server-switch-hook` can help perhaps (untested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always choose the `--eval` option of `emacsclient` to perform more complicated tasks:

```sh
emacsclient --eval "(progn (find-file \"$FILE\") (goto-line $NUM) (forward-char $COL) (recenter))"
```

Comment: Can made to work with `--alternate-editor=emacs` ? - It doesn't open the file or go to the line.

Comment: @ideasman42 One option would be to remove `--alternate-editor=emacs` and let `emacsclient` start `emacs --daemon` and to connect to that emacs server instance by default. [Please see the documentation of emacs-client in this respect.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html) If that does not work for you for any reason you can also write the eval into the `--alternate-editor` command.

Comment: Re: *"you can also write the eval into the `--alternate-editor` command."* - How would this be done? - its already taking part of the `--eval`, its just using it as a filename instead of evaluating it.